# yum + list all available security updates without installing them, on redhat 5?

Tags: linux, redhat, yum

To list all available security updates without installing them, I run this

and this syntax is working on redhat 6 and 7

```
 # yum list-security --security
```

please advice what is the syntax for redhat 5?

I try the

```
 yum list-security --security
```

but this syntax not runing corectly on redhat 5

---

from redhat doc -

For Red Hat Enterprise Linux 5

To list all available security updates without installing them, run:
Raw

```
     # yum list-security --security
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to first install the yum security plugin.

```
# yum install yum-security
```

Then do, as you have above.

```
# yum list-security --security
```

Note, I don't have a RHEL5 system around any more to test this.

Source: https://access.redhat.com/solutions/10021

Comment: what agreat answer -:)